# UITableView cell color does not disappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when i click on any cell text it become blue and when i came back again on same it still remains blue till i click another cell how to resolve this issue 
I am using UITableView with detail text label.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell1.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:img];
    [img release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your class:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // this UIViewController is about to re-appear, make sure we remove the current selection in our table view
    NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Deselect your row in delegate's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    ...
}
```

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
 CategoriesList *dvController = [[CategoriesList alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoriesList" bundle:nil];
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 //dvController.description = description; 
 //dvController.title=title;
 //dvController.descriptionImage=descriptionImage;

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
 [dvController release];
 
}

Comment: @ali "not working" is a bad description. What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the selection style when the user selected a row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    .. your view changing code
}
```

Comment: i am doing like this its working fine with one controller but in second view when i go there and clicl back button to move table view it gives exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as following :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];  
}
```

And add

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndex`